# How to set a machine as Task-Tracker in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I am new to hadoop framework and I was following the book “Hadoop in Action”. I am able to set up pseudo-distributed environment with Ubantu.
I have one doubt regarding Task-Tracker and DataNode.

We are assigning NameNode in core-site.xml and Job-Tracker in mapred-site.xml.
Where will we define about the task-tracker and DataNode.
Let’s say I have a machine “xye3434” and I want to use it as a Task-Tracker, how can I define this?
Is there some setting in xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the TastTrackers/DataNodes should be specified in the **conf/slaves** file in the Hadoop installation folder. bin/start-dfs.sh and bin/start-mapred.sh scripts will iterate through the slaves file and then login to the machine using password less ssh and then start the appropriate daemons on all the slaves.

Comment: Thanks a lot Praveen for answer.I notice that you are very active member in hadoop community. I was expecting that you will answer this question.I wanted to ask-do we have some properties also which we can set in xml files? or only conf/slaves files are the only option.